# Updating entire row efficiently using Merge

Tags: sql-server

I am designing a stored procedure which will run on a schedule. It's purpose is to update a table based on results from an OpenQuery. The OpenQuery will return some completely new records, and some updated records. I currently have this written in such a manner.

```
DELETE A
FROM TableA A
JOIN @OpenQueryResult B
  ON A.Key1 = B.Key1 AND A.Key2 = B.Key2

INSERT INTO TableA
(.
.
.)
SELECT 
.
.
.
FROM @OpenQueryResult
```

Note: `TableA` has all the columns from `@OpenQueryResult` in addition to several calculated fields.

I would like to find a better way to do this. Through some research, it seems that [Merge](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) would be a good choice as it cuts down on overhead, and thus, execution time. I imagine things looking a little like this:

```
MERGE TableA AS target
USING @OpenQueryResult AS source
ON (target.Key1 = source.Key1 AND target.Key2 = source.Key2)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE ...
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT ...
  VALUES ...
```

All the examples I've seen online explicitly list the columns that should be updated. Is there a shortcut to say "copy all matching column names"? TableA is rather massive in terms of number of columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a shortcut to say "copy all matching column names"?

Nope. Gotta list them all.  You can usually copy/paste the column list from somewhere.  For example, `right click -> script -> script as select` gives you a comma-separated column list.